# Official grammar

Tags: grammaire, académie-française

I am not quite sure but I think that the French Academy (Académie française) is the French institution that is the canonical guardian of the French language.
([What organization is the official guardian of the French language in France and/or worldwide?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18405/what-organization-is-the-official-guardian-of-the-french-language-in-france-and)). I do know that there was a French Grammar supervised by the French Academy
([LA GRAMMAIRE DE L’ACADÉMIE: PAR M. ABEL HERMANT, DÉLÉGUÉ DE L’ACADÉMIE FRANÇAISE, 1930](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-grammaire-de-lacademie-francaise)).

Has this grammar ever been considered  as the official French Grammar? What was the reactions to this work? Is there something relevant but more recent one?
Is Grevisse's Le Bon usage considered as the Definite French Grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official? Definite? What do you mean?
[mode_trolling]Grevisse? He's Belgian! How do you want his work to become *official*?[/mode_trolling] No disrespect meant!

**A/** The *Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française* is truely *official* in that it is the only french dictionnary to be published by the *Journal Officiel de la République Française*, which says the law in every matter, language included.
Any official document written by the government **must** be fully in accordance with that dictionnary, period.

This fact and only this fact makes it official... and in France... only!

**B/** Grammar is different. Grammar is a matter of aesthetics. And therefore... each to his own.
Being well known that grammarians always disagree... (*Grammatici certant et adhuc sub judice lis est*), best in class grammarians will only observe and report how the language is written in reknown works. *Le bon usage* is indeed a good reference, because it is an example of that attitude. How things are written by some *bons auteurs* is as important as whatever so called *rule*.

Because, in France, you know,... no honest grammarian will tell you that you must not write : *Sous le pont Mirabeau **coule** la Seine et nos amours*...

Comment: Not everyone agree about *coule* lack of agreement: http://salon-litteraire.linternaute.com/fr/guillaume-apollinaire/review/1938902-mirabeau-bridge-querelle-orthographique-a-propos-de-guillaume-apollinaire

Comment: As a matter of fact, the paper you quoted only mentions *professeurs de lettres* no contemporary grammarian at all. That not everyone agree is a fact (I wrote *each to his own*) but the same with whatever artwork. Grammarians just take note. And, when surprised, they just don't claim having found some fault. They just wonder. Did I understand correctly ? That's called *descriptivism* and that's what grammar is nowadays.

Comment: Indeed. I fully agree with the fact grammar is not an exact science and should not be "*prescristivist*" only. However, your quote might not be the best choice to show your point. By removing its newlines and truncating verses, you distort Apollinaire's words and show a blatantly non grammatical sentence by common standards while the original work is only possibly ambiguous. By the way, Grevisse was Belgian, not belgium :-)

Comment: @aCOSwt Thanks for the answer. I found also this article http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article162. By the way what is [mode_trolling]?

Comment: @dimitris it refers to [internet trolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll). Trolling is "being a troll", so basically these false tags surrounding the sentence are there to indicate he's joking/provoking

Comment: Est-ce possible svp de mettre de côté les tags de langage de programmation. À mon avis ce genre de trucs n'a pas sa place dans les réponses ni en langue française généralement. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

To answer to the first part of the question (Grammaire de l'Académie française : réactions) I found this interesting [article](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article162). One reads, among other things:

> Non. Il n’existe pas de grammaire officielle. L’Académie s’est essayée
> à l’exercice dans les années trente... avec un succès qu’on peut
> qualifier de « très relatif ». Le débat à ce propos permit de revenir
> sur la personnalité d’Abel Hermant et la contestation approndie des
> erreurs académiques par Ferdinand Brunot.

(...)

> **La Grammaire de l’Académie vue par l’Académie**
>
> Voici ce que l’on trouve sur le site de l’Académie française (choisir
> la rubrique Dictionnaire, puis l’avant-propos de la IXe édition).
>
> « On a souvent rappelé que, d’après les statuts d’établissement de
> 1635, l’Académie devait, en même temps que le Dictionnaire, composer
> une grammaire. Elle s’y essaya par deux fois, sans trop de réussite.
> Sa première grammaire, due à la plume de Régnier-Desmarais, et publiée
> au début du XVIIIe siècle, fut jugée comme une production bien
> imparfaite. L’Académie attendit deux cents ans pour récidiver ; elle
> aurait pu attendre plus longtemps encore, car la grammaire qu’elle
> édita dans les années trente du XXe siècle n’eut guère de succès,
> fût-ce d’estime. »

One contemporary review from that era can be found [here](https://www.persee.fr/doc/rbph_0035-0818_1933_num_12_3_1414_t1_0700_0000_2).

Answer (score 1):

The Academie can blather on, but the one that all French people use regularly is the one from http://bescherelle.com/.